# Community Promotion Ads - 1H 2011

Tags: discussion, community-ads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Community Promotion Ads - 1H 2012](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/614/community-promotion-ads-1h-2012)

#### What in the Wide, Wide World of Sports is Going On Here?

TL;DR -- put images and links in the answers. If they get voted up enough, they will appear on the main site as community promotion ads.

#### But whyyyyyyy?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- cool webmaster tools
- the site's twitter account
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. And to click on it for great justice!

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently 6) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/448).

Answer (score 9):

[image: Follow us on Twitter]

Comment: Wow no idea there was even a Twitter lol

Comment: Is it just a feed of latest questions?

Answer (score 1):

[image: Search Available Domains]