# How can we get more high rep users to post questions?

Tags: discussion, activity

I [posted about the fact that high rep users weren't asking enough questions before](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/660/state-of-the-questions-2012-and-what-we-can-do-to-improve). However, that post hasn't really gotten more people to post questions.

So, does anyone have any good ideas on how to motivate high rep users to post more questions. A [community add](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/614/community-promotion-ads-2012/674#674) might work, but I have the feeling that we're going to need more than that.

Comment: I've got a question in mind, but I'm thinking how to phrase it, without it being too open ended and promoting discussion. The trouble is I know the rules too well!

Answer (score 1):

I've been busying myself looking at the [200 or so unanswered questions](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=unanswered) we have floating about - getting some of those knocked out might help our cause somewhat?

Comment: Yes, good idea. It actually says **634** questions. Note that about half that number have answers, but the answers are not upvoted. [See here](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=votes). So it would also be a good idea to upvote all good answers you see on those questions!

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat I had a bash at a few over the weekend, there are quite a few decent questions there, looking at the view count they do appear to attract people via search engines